# Java compiler doesn't compile all subfolders after the first compile

Tags: java

I have a problem with the java compiler.
The folders of my java project looks like this:

- main folder

  - delivery folder

    - Box.java
    - Factory.java
    - FragileBox.java
    - Supplier.java
  - test folder

    - Test.java
    - Test2.java
    - Test3.java
    - Test4.java
    - Test5.java
  - DeliveryTest.java

Clearly I have 2 packages aswell, a `delivery package` and a `test package`. It's a school project, so the `test package` was given, we had to write the `delivery package` which is tested by the `test package`.

The DeliveryTest.java looks like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import test.*;

import delivery.*;

public class DeliveryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>();
        tests.add(new Test2());
        tests.add(new Test3());
        tests.add(new Test4());
        tests.add(new Test5());

        int level = 1;

        for (Test test : tests) {
            if (test.test()) {
                ++level;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Az elert szint: " + level);
    }
}
```

I really don't want to detail the work and the purpose of the code, I don't think it's relevant here.
My problem is that if I compile the DeliveryTest.java as `javac DeliveryTest.java`, it creates the class files, and successfully compiles, but: after the first compile, when all the class files created I make any changes on `delivery package` it won't compile again, only the `test package`, and after compiler finishes the compile it will just return as everything went well. It won't even create the class files again if I remove one of the class files from the `delivery folder`. However, the `test package` compiles fine after the first compile, it has no problem with that.
How can I achieve that I can compile the *delivery* package aswell after the first compile?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I suggest you use a build tool like maven or gradle AND an IDE.  This way you can edit code and press the `Run` button to run the latest version of your code. Also `Debug` to debug it etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java compiler doesn't look around for files to compile. If you call it from the command line, you better use a call that names all Java files in their folders. Assuming that the main folder is your working directory,

```
javac DeliveryTest.java delivery/*.java test/*.java
```

If you don't change files in the test package you may not have to use the last parameter.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for clearing this up for me. Have a nice day.